# Function doesnt work while geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var xmldoc= loadXMLDoc("skoly.xml");
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var skoly = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("skoly");

function dislplayXML (xmldoc){
alert("dislplayXML ");
  var d = document.createElement('div'); 
  var t = document.createTextNode(xmldoc.xml); 
  d.appendChild(t);
  document.write('<pre>' + d.innerHTML + '</pre>');
}
function geocode(address) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
geocode("Praha");  
dislplayXML (xmldoc); 
alert("end");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works there is no problem. BUT i need to call `dislplayXML (xmldoc);` in geocode function. When I try it alerts"dislplayXML " but rest of the function doesn't do anything. Any ideas why?

PLEASE don't care about loadxmldoc.js, loadXMLDoc or skoly.xml. That is not important. xmldoc is xmlDOM.

Comment: you can't use `document.write` in an asynchronous callback...it will wipe out the whole page. Use your browser console to look at errors thrown....will find out why your function is failing.

Comment: Ok thanks for information, is there any way to make dislplayXML (xmldoc); wait for geocoding? Becouse I need to run this function after I get results of geocoding.

Comment: need to run it in callback of geocoding then

Comment: If I run dislplayXML (xmldoc); in callback of geocoding it  alerts"dislplayXML " again and rest of the fuction doesnt do anything again. Is something I could use insted of document.write?